# Why uiautomatorviewer failed to take screen shot of audio trimmer?

Tags: appium, uiautomatorviewer

My audio picker library is opening in app as bottom sheet dialogue fragment.
But whenever i try to take screen shot using uiautomatorviewer it gives error remote object doesn't exist.

please help me to solve issue.

Answer (score 0):

At Java I use next construction to tyhat purpose and its worked forme:

```
File srcFile=driverA.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```